# Discussion : Why 'too broad' reason has been removed as flag reason

Tags: discussion

I was recently thinking of flagging a question "too broad" as the question was asking for entire feature and not any specific question. But noticed that it has been removed. Is there any specific reason it has been removed?

**EDIT**

I have flagged the post as "Needs more focus" for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Half a year ago, [new post notices were introduced on Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700/295232), which came with renaming of <s>some</s> almost all of the close reasons. As you've seen, 'Too broad' became 'Needs more focus', 'Unclear what you're asking' became 'Needs details or clarity', 'Off-topic' became 'A community-specific reason' and 'Primarily opinion based' became 'Opinion based'. I don't know if a mapping table exist, but you can compare the table from [my answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339713/295232) with the old reasons:

[image]

with the [new ones](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1163009) (only those between 101 and 105 are used, the others are *very* old ones):

[image]